# Regex: Do not match if pattern at the end of the string

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have the following regex, where I want to match any explicit dot followed by one or more:

```
<b> <i> <u> </b> </i> </u>
```

I would like this Regex to NOT match this pattern if it occurs at the end of the string.

```
string = Regex.Replace(string, "\.((<[\/biu]+>)+)", ".$1||")
```

Ex:

```
This <b>should match.</b> allright.

This <i><b>shouldn't match.</b></i>
```

Answer (score 13):

```
"\.((<[\/biu]+>)+)(?!$)"
```

Use the negative lookahead assertion with the `$` symbol to check for end of line. (Remember, `$` matches end of line so you want to *not* match that.)

Comment: Thanks, but it still matches ".</b>" in the following:
This <i><b>shouldn't match.</b></i>

Comment: You could always make it non-greedy by introducing the `?` symbol. That would probably make it not match what you wrote. (I don't have any resource to test with right now)

Comment: upvoted because answer matches title, and was exactly what I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 5):

You could use [atomic grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html):

```
\.(?>(?:<\/?[biu]>)+)(?!$)
```

Comment: The OP was capturing the tags and plugging them back in with $1, so he should add capturing parens instead of a lookahead.  Also, this is the only answer that corrects the OP's mistake WRT matching the tags.

Answer (score 3):

Force there to be more items after the last closed element, but make sure they aren't elements themselves.

```
"\.((<[\/biu]+>)+)[^<>]+"
```